# Using hook_form_alter() only on loading

Tags: forms, hooks

I am using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) in  Drupal 6, which successfully works. As for now, when I submit the form, it again runs the same hook. I want to run it only on load and edit.

Do you have any idea on how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code for the load operation of existing forms

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if(empty($form_state['post'])) {
    //do you load operation
  }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure this works, as [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6) set `$form_state['post']` with `$form_state['post'] = $_POST;` right before invoking `hook_form_alter()`.